# FOSElasticaBundle order query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am integrating FOSElasticaBundle in my Symfony 2.3 project and I need to sort the results by their price property.

Here is my code:

```
   $finder     = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.product');
   $fieldTerms = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
   $fieldTerms->setTerms('taxon_ids', $taxon_ids_array);
   $boolQuery->addMust($fieldTerms);

   $resultSet = $finder->find($boolQuery);
```

How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try create a `\Elastica\Query` object which also contains the sorting information, then send this to the finder:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.product');

$fieldTerms = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
$fieldTerms->setTerms('taxon_ids', $taxon_ids_array);
$boolQuery->addMust($fieldTerms);

$finalQuery = new \Elastica\Query($boolQuery);

$finalQuery->setSort(array('price' => array('order' => 'asc')));

$resultSet = $finder->find($finalQuery);
```

Have a look [at the elasticsearch docs on the sort parameter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/) to see how to use it properly.

NOTE: `\Elastica\Query` is quite different to `\Elastica\Query\AbstractQuery`, the first encapsulates everything you could send to the `_search` API endpoint (facets, sorting, explain, etc...) The `AbstractQuery` represents a base type for each of the individual query types (range, fuzzy, terms, etc...).

Comment: by this way i can sort fields except the integer ones. do you have any idea?